# При повторной передаче имею ошибку TypeError: missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

Господа, имею проблему. Подтягиваю значения из базы данных, визуализированные посредством метода Treeview в сторонее окно. В первый раз подтягивается, но когда хочу его изменить и вызвать окно с Treeview еще раз, то получаю ошибку TypeError: WindowMashins() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'. 
Вот окно, из которого осуществляю вызов базы

```
from WindowMashins import Basad
from SetSizes import SetSizes
from OperationSwitch import OperationSwitch
from InductorParams import InductorParams
from Materials import Materials
class EntranceDataFirst():
    def __init__(self):
        self.bif1=""
        self.GUI(self.bif1)
    def GUI(self, bif1):
        self.EntranceDataWindow = Tk()
        self.EntranceDataWindow.geometry('640x700')  # геометрия окна
        self.EntranceDataWindow.title("Параметры для расчета технологического процесса МИОМ")  # название окна
        self.frame = Frame(self.EntranceDataWindow, relief=RAISED, borderwidth=1)
        self.frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
        btn1 = Button(self.frame, text="Выбор оборудования", bg="blue", fg="black", command=self.WindowMashins)
        btn2 = Button(self.frame, text="Выбор операции", bg="blue", fg="black", command=self.WindowOperationSwitch)
        btn3 = Button(self.frame, text="Выбор материала", bg="blue", fg="black", command=self.WindowMaterials)
        btn4 = Button(self.frame, text="Размер заготовки", bg="blue", fg="black", command=self.SetSizes)
        self.message_entry = Entry(self.frame, textvariable='')
        self.message_entry.insert(0, bif1)
        self.message_entry.place(x=350, y=100)
        self.message_entry1 = Entry(self.frame, textvariable='')
        self.message_entry1.place(x=350, y=200)
        self.message_entry2 = Entry(self.frame, textvariable='')
        self.message_entry2.place(x=350, y=300)
        self.message_entry3 = Entry(self.frame, textvariable='')
        self.message_entry3.place(x=350, y=400)
        btn1.place(x=50, y=100)
        btn2.place(x=50, y=200)
        btn3.place(x=50, y=300)
        btn4.place(x=50, y=400)
        closeButton = Button(self.EntranceDataWindow, text="Close", command=quit)
        closeButton.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=5, pady=5)
        okButton = Button(self.EntranceDataWindow, text="OK")
        okButton.pack(side=RIGHT)
        self.EntranceDataWindow.mainloop()
    def WindowMashins(self):
        self.EntranceDataWindow.destroy()
        self.bif1=''
        window=Basad()
```

отыгрывает процедура WindowMashins. При этом само окно закрывается при помощи  destroy.

вот окно с базой

```
import sqlite3
from SQL12 import *
import EntranceData
from Terminator import Terminator
from EditorMashins import *
class Basad():
    def GUI (self):
        self.BasaM2 = Tk()
        self.BasaM2.geometry('1800x1000')
        self.BasaM2.title("Выбор оборудования МИОМ")
        self.Tree = ttk.Treeview(self.BasaM2, columns=(
        "Name", "Max_change_energi", "Condenser_capasity", "Equipment_induct", "SccF", "K1", "K2"), height=5,
                                 show='headings')
        self.Tree.column("Name", width=250, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.Tree.column("Max_change_energi", width=190, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.Tree.column("Condenser_capasity", width=250, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.Tree.column("Equipment_induct", width=230, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.Tree.column("SccF", width=280, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.Tree.column("K1", width=60, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.Tree.column("K2", width=50, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.Tree['show'] = "headings"
        self.Tree.heading("Name", text="Наименование оборудования")
        self.Tree.heading("Max_change_energi", text="Максимальная энергия")
        self.Tree.heading("Condenser_capasity", text="Емкость батареи кондецаторов")
        self.Tree.heading("Equipment_induct", text=" Собственная индуктивность")
        self.Tree.heading("SccF", text="Частота тока короткого замыкания")
        self.Tree.heading("K1", text="K1")
        self.Tree.heading("K2", text="K2")
        self.Tree.place(x=400, y=10)
        self.slct2 = ['Выбери из таблицы', 'Выбери из таблицы', 'Выбери из таблицы', 'Выбери из таблицы',
                      'Выбери из таблицы', 'Выбери из таблицы', 'Выбери из таблицы']
        self.field1 = self.slct2[0]
        self.field2 = self.slct2[1]
        self.field3 = self.slct2[2]
        self.field4 = self.slct2[3]
        self.field5 = self.slct2[4]
        self.field6 = self.slct2[5]
        self.field7 = self.slct2[6]
        self.btn = Button(self.BasaM2, text="Добавить оборудование", bg="grey", fg="black",
                          command=self.AddMashins)  # описание объекта типа button названия кнопки
        self.btn.place(x=250, y=800)  # расположение кнопки
        self.btn5 = Button(self.BasaM2, text="Редактировать оборудование", bg="grey", fg="black",
                           command=self.clicked2)  # описание объекта типа button названия кнопки
        self.btn5.place(x=750, y=800)  # расположение кнопки
        self.btn2 = Button(self.BasaM2, text="Удалить оборудование", bg="grey", fg="black",
                           command=self.DellMashins)  # описание объекта типа button названия кнопки
        self.btn2.place(x=500, y=800)  # расположение кнопки
        self.btn3 = Button(self.BasaM2, text="Применить", bg="grey", fg="black",
                           command=self.SelectlMashins)  # описание объекта типа button названия кнопки
        self.btn3.place(x=1000, y=800)  # расположение кнопки
        self.btn1 = Button(self.BasaM2, text="Отменить", bg='pink', fg='red', command=self.BasaM2.destroy)
        self.btn1.place(x=1250, y=800)
        self.btn4 = Button(self.BasaM2, text="Взять данные в работу", bg='green', fg='black', command=self.GoToWork)
        self.btn4.place(x=50, y=800)
        if self.field1 == 'Выбери из таблицы': self.btn4['state'] = 'disabled'
        label1 = Label(self.BasaM2, text="Название оборудования", bg="grey", fg="black")
        self.message_entry = Entry(self.BasaM2, textvariable='')
        self.message_entry.insert(0, self.field1)
        self.message_entry.place(x=50, y=75)
        label2 = Label(self.BasaM2, text="Максимальная энергия заряда", bg="grey", fg="black")
        self.message_entry1 = Entry(self.BasaM2, textvariable='')
        self.message_entry1.place(x=50, y=175)
        self.message_entry1.insert(0, self.field2)
        label3 = Label(self.BasaM2, text="Емкость батареи кондецаторов", bg="grey", fg="black")
        self.message_entry2 = Entry(self.BasaM2, textvariable='')
        self.message_entry2.place(x=50, y=275)
        self.message_entry2.insert(0, self.field3)
        label4 = Label(self.BasaM2, text="Собственная индуктивность разрядного контура", bg="grey", fg="black")
        self.message_entry3 = Entry(self.BasaM2, textvariable='')
        self.message_entry3.place(x=50, y=375)
        self.message_entry3.insert(0, self.field4)
        label5 = Label(self.BasaM2, text="Частота тока короткого замыкания", bg="grey", fg="black")
        self.message_entry4 = Entry(self.BasaM2, textvariable='')
        self.message_entry4.place(x=50, y=475)
        self.message_entry4.insert(0, self.field5)
        label6 = Label(self.BasaM2, text="K1", bg="grey", fg="black")
        self.message_entry5 = Entry(self.BasaM2, textvariable='')
        self.message_entry5.place(x=50, y=575)
        self.message_entry5.insert(0, self.field6)
        label7 = Label(self.BasaM2, text="K2", bg="grey", fg="black")
        self.message_entry6 = Entry(self.BasaM2, textvariable=self.field7)
        self.message_entry6.place(x=50, y=675)
        self.message_entry6.insert(0, self.field7)
        label1.place(x=50, y=50)
        label2.place(x=50, y=150)
        label3.place(x=50, y=250)
        label4.place(x=50, y=350)
        label5.place(x=50, y=450)
        label6.place(x=50, y=550)
        label7.place(x=50, y=650)
    def clicked2(self):
        sel = self.Tree.focus()
        self.slct2 = self.Tree.item(sel, option='values')
        self.field1 = self.slct2[0]
        self.field2 = self.slct2[1]
        self.field3 = self.slct2[2]
        self.field4 = self.slct2[3]
        self.field5 = self.slct2[4]
        self.field6 = self.slct2[5]
        self.field7 = self.slct2[6]
        NewWindow = Editor(self.field1, self.field2, self.field3, self.field4, self.field5, self.field6, self.field7)
    def AddMashins(self):
        self.field1 = ""
        self.field2 = ""
        self.field3 = ""
        self.field4 = ""
        self.field5 = ""
        self.field6 = ""
        self.field7 = ""
        NewWindow = Editor(self.field1, self.field2, self.field3, self.field4, self.field5, self.field6, self.field7)
    def DellMashins(self):
        sel = self.Tree.focus()
        self.slct2 = self.Tree.item(sel, option='values')
        self.field1=self.slct2[0]
        print(self.slct2)
        print(self.slct2[0])
        print(self.field1)
        NewWindow2 = Terminator(self.field1)
    def SelectlMashins(self):
        self.btn4['state'] = 'active'
        sel=self.Tree.focus()
        self.message_entry.delete(0, END)
        self.message_entry1.delete(0, END)
        self.message_entry2.delete(0, END)
        self.message_entry3.delete(0, END)
        self.message_entry4.delete(0, END)
        self.message_entry5.delete(0, END)
        self.message_entry6.delete(0, END)
        self.slct2=self.Tree.item(sel, option='values')
        self.field1=self.slct2[0]
        self.message_entry.insert(0, self.field1)
        self.field2=self.slct2[1]
        self.message_entry1.insert(0, self.field2)
        self.field3=self.slct2[2]
        self.message_entry2.insert(0, self.field3)
        self.field4=self.slct2[3]
        self.message_entry3.insert(0, self.field4)
        self.field5=self.slct2[4]
        self.message_entry4.insert(0, self.field5)
        self.field6=self.slct2[5]
        self.message_entry5.insert(0, self.field6)
        self.field7=self.slct2[6]
        self.message_entry6.insert(0, self.field7)
        print("наименование оборудования "+self.field1)
        print("максимальная энергия"+self.field2)
        print('Емкость батарей конденсаторов ' + self.field3)
        print('Собственная индуктивность ' + self.field4)
        print('Частота тока короткого замыкания '+self.field5)
        print('K1 '+ self.field6)
        print("K2 "+ self.field7)
        print(self.slct2)
    def view_records(self):
        mt = sqlite3.connect("mashins.db")
        cursor = mt.cursor()
        cursor.execute(sql6)
        cursor.execute(sql6)
        for row in cursor.execute(sql6): print(row)
        cpt = 0  # Counter representing the ID of your code.
        for row in cursor.execute(sql6):
            # I suppose the first column of your table is ID
            self.Tree.insert('', 'end', text=str(cpt), values=row)
            cpt += 1  # increment the I
    def GoToWork(self):
        self.BasaM2.destroy()
        EntranceData.EntranceDataFirst.GUI(EntranceData.EntranceDataFirst,self.field1)
    def __init__(self):
        self.GUI()
        self.view_records()
        self.BasaM2.mainloop()
```

Процедура GoToWork возвращает нужное значение на предыдущую форму, при этом есть destroy предыдущего окна.
все вроде бы работает, но при повторном вызове базы возникает ошибка TypeError. Читал, что необходимо заводить и во воремя уничтожать объект класса. Подозреваю, что я не правильно использую Treeview. Был бы благодарен за комментарии.

Comment: И что вы хотели этим сказать? `EntranceData.EntranceDataFirst.GUI(EntranceData.EntranceDataFirst,self.field1)`

Comment: Отедактируйте нормально постинг -- у вас текст программы слился с текстом вопроса. Для подсветки удобно пользоваться специальным хинтом `<!-- language: lang-py -->`.

Comment: я хотел как можно конкретней вставить название класса и передать парамтр. Думаете проблема в этом?

Comment: Изменил по вашему совету.... завел объект класса, сослался при вызове процедуры и старого окна. Ошибка и правда пропала, но появилась новая проблема. Сначала вылезает окно с пустыми окнами, и только если его закрыть, появляется правильное...разбираюсь

Comment: Добавьте кусочек, который вы изменили. Проблема, скорее всего в том, что вы вначале конструктором создаёте окошко с данными по умолчанию, а вам надо сразу инициализировать правильным образом. Почитайте как в Питоне ООП работает.

Comment: `def GoToWork(self):
        self.BasaM2.destroy()
        f=EntranceData.EntranceDataFirst()
        f.GUI(self.field1)`    вот как-то так  @0andriy

Comment: дадите ссылку, что почитать? скорее всего вы правы, я инициализирую его по умолчанию, а как передать ему данные не знаю

Comment: Слушайте, спасибо огромное! Разобрался и все работает. Благодарю вас!

Answer (score 0):

Не правильно вызывал окно. Для того, чтобы все было правильно, нужно было при повторном вызове формы с результатами выборки из базы данных инициализировать её как объект класса c передачей классу соотвествующего параметра, а не пытаться вызвать путем вызова процедуры GUI с передачей1 параметра ей.
Вот так должно было быть

```
 def GoToWork(self):
        self.BasaM2.destroy()
        f=EntranceData.EntranceDataFirst(self.field1)
```